# Sed/awk command to replace a pattern while preserving spaces

Tags: bash, unix, awk, sed

I have multiple files in my directory which have a line with pattern like this:

```
.declare  trading_name__w       a22
.declare  trading_name__w  a22
.declare  trading_name__w             a22
```

I want to replace the word `a22` with `a40`, keeping spacing between words consistent (as they are in original file).

I tried with this command:

```
sed 's/trading_name__w\([^%]\+\)a22/trading_name__w\([^%]\+\)a40/g' filename
```

but it disturbs spacing between words:

```
.declare  trading_name__w([^%]+)a40
```

How can I do this with sed or awk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `\1` in the replacement string to copy the capture group.

```
sed 's/trading_name__w\([^%]\+\)a22/trading_name__w\1a40/g' filename
```